# Simplest Linux for Cyclone V - Arm Cortex A9

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, usb-drive, ethernet

I am looking for a simple linux that works for Cyclone V - Arm Cortex A9. I need something that boots very quickly, and the only functionality I want is to be able to mount a USB flash drive and then send those files to a host via Ethernet thats connected to my board.

Please any and all help on source code, tutorials, where to start, is appreciated.

Comment: Any "lightweight" linux will do. There are plenty of minimalist tiny linux distributions. just check out distrowatch.com. For example you could use Raspbian mini-version, which you can find on raspberrypi.org.

Comment: With above system my Pi boots in less than 30 seconds, so with your Cortex thing it should be like 15 seconds or less.

Comment: Thanks! I also want a full blown Linux on my system eventually, is it possible to load the simple linux and then boot the full blown Linux and handover the core to the full blown Linux. As in make it so the simple linux doesn't access the Core once the other has booted?

Comment: Do you mean a dual-boot setup?

Comment: Sorta. I want the simple linux to boot, but also Ubuntu. And once Ubuntu has booted I don't need my simple linux system. The reason I need simple linux is because I need to access some file in 1 second of power on, but Ubuntu won't be loaded by then.

Comment: I think the easiest solution would be to just use dual-boot. I mean you could use a virtual machine inside the "simple linux" but this would mean slower boot times and a much much more complicated setup. Therefore in your case I just recommend making a basic dual-boot setup.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have Ubuntu anyway, you don't need to install another distribution. Have a bootloader entry that runs a single program instead of a normal session. That is, make the default boot

```
linux /vmlinuz root=/dev/sda ro init=/usr/local/sbin/simple-ftp-only
```

(apart from the `init=…` part, copy what's already there in the default entry). You can use one of [many multiboot solutions](http://www.multibootpi.com/).

The script `simple-ftp-only` would probably just set up the network (call `ifconfig` to set up a fixed IP address, call `route` if you need to contact a host that isn't on the local network link) and run a TFTP or FTP server. And possibly offer a way to reboot to the “real” system.

Instead of an alternate `init`, you could put the TFTP server in the [initramfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initramfs). If you do that, you don't need to change anything to the bootloader, but instead you do need to tweak the initramfs scripts. The core scripts are located in `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts`; you can add your own under `/etc/initramfs-tools/scripts`.